# Como depurar um serviço Windows?

Tags: c#, windows

Eu fiz um Serviço Windows de Envio de E-mails de 5 em 5 minutos e gostaria de saber como depurar ele.

Eu vi vários tutoriais na internet, mas não consegui realizar a depuração.

Alguém saberia explicar como eu depuraria o serviço?

Comment: `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();`?

Comment: Coloquei essa linha no método OnStart do serviço

Comment: Se estiver utilizando o Visual Studio, você pode realizar um "Attach to Process".
Para isso vá em _Debug->Attach to Process_ .
Na janela que abrirá, marque a opção de exibir processos de todos usuários e procure pelo processo do serviço que deseja depurar.
Não esqueça de adicionar um breakpoint ao código.

Comment: Fiz isso e mesmo assim não depura...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recentemente também fiz um serviço para Windows em C# e utilizei o [topshelf](http://topshelf-project.com/). Ele permite você desenvolver o serviço como um `console aplication` e com isso você pode debugar normalmente. Quando seu serviço estiver pronto, você instalar o arquivo `.exe` gerado pelo projeto como um serviço do Windows.

Comment: Vou verificar, obrigado!